# Assets/Script/Scoreboard.cs(33,2): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `{'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Checked the script but still not solved

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Scoreboard : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public GameObject[] stars;
    private int coinsCount;
    void Start()
    {
         coinsCount = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("coin").Length;
    }


    public void starsAcheived()
    {
        int coinsLeft = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("coin").Length;
        int coinsCollected = coinsCount - coinsLeft;

        float percentage = float.Parse( coinsCollected.ToString()) / float.Parse(coinsCount.ToString()) * 100f;

         if (percentage >= 33f && percentage < 65)
        {
          stars[0].SetActive(true);//one stars
        }
        else if (percentage >= 65 && percentage < 76)
        {
         stars[0].SetActive(true);
         stars[1].SetActive(true);// two stars
        }
        else (percentage>= 76)
        {
         stars[0].SetActive(true);
         stars[1].SetActive(true);
         stars[2].SetActive(true);// three stars
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow does not have line numbers.  Which line causes the error?

Answer (score 6):

An `else` statement cannot have a condition, so `else (percentage >= 76)` is invalid.

Using this instead:

```
else
{
    stars[0].SetActive(true);
    stars[1].SetActive(true);
    stars[2].SetActive(true);// three stars
}
```

Will cause the code to run for any criteria that doesn't match any of the previous `if`...`else if` statements.

But it looks like you just need another `else if`:

```
else if (percentage >= 76)
```

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions such as those caused by a typo

Comment: @Ruzihm but is this a typo or misunderstanding?

Comment: @Ruzihm in This case I wouldn't downvote the answer, the question is still that basic that itself is downvoted and closed correctly (not sure about the closing reason though). The answer was there before it was declared off-topic though and is per se not incorrect. But that's only my opinions ofcourse.